# When 2D array is read by program pointer to array outputs incorrect values, but vector outputs correct values

Tags: c++, arrays, file, pointers, vector

I'm doing homework where my program needs to read 2D array from file. I have to use pointer to array, that's the point of homework. For testing purposes i also included vector. When matrix is outputed ponter to array outputs incorrect values but vector outputs correct ones. When tested on bigger arrays (100 by 50) pointer to array outputed also good values among incorrect values. But I don't include it here because of its size. What am I doing wrong?
Here is input part of code:

```
 Matrix (std::istream &is)
    {
        is >> n_ >> m_;
        int counter = 0;
        int matrix_temp[n_ * m_];
        while(counter < (n_ * m_))
        {
            int x = 0;
            is >> x;
            matrix_temp[counter] = x;
            vector_test.push_back(x); 
            counter ++;
        }
        mat_ = matrix_temp;
    }
```

Here are class varaibles:

```
private:
    int n_;//wiersze
    int m_;//kolumny
    int *mat_;
    std::vector<int> wektor;
```

Here is output part of code:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<< (std::ostream &os, const Matrix &m)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int size = m.n_ * m.m_;
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        {
            os << counter <<"\t "<<*(m.mat_ + counter) <<"\t"<<m.vector_test[i]<<std::endl;
            counter ++;
        }
        return os;
    }
```

Main:

```
int main()
{
Matrix matrix = Matrix(std::cin);
std::cout << matrix;
}
```

Input file (first line is size: lines and columns):

```
5   3
3   3   3
3   3   3
3   3   3
3   3   3
3   3   3
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Just where do you think `int matrix_temp[n_ * m_];` is stored, and where does `int *mat_;` point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I have solved it using malloc. Here is the working part of code:

```
  Matrix (std::istream &is)
    {
        is >> n_ >> m_;
        int counter = 0;
        mat_ = (int*)malloc((n_* m_)*sizeof(int));
        while(counter < (n_ * m_))
        {
            int x = 0;
            is >> x;
            mat_[counter] = x;
            vector_test.push_back(x); 
            counter ++;
        }
        
    }
```

Hope it helps other souls tormented by univeristies.